# DateTime Conversion failing, String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Why this datetime conversion is failing?

```
string CompletedDateTime ="2016-01-08 03:47:03.000";
DateTime cDate =  DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", CompletedDateTime , null);
```

> Exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
DateTime cDate =  DateTime.ParseExact(CompletedDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The problem is that you used the wrong order in the paramteres you passed. The signature of the method is this one:

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(
    string s,
    string format,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```

For further information about this method, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Furthermorem you have also a minor bug in the format, you pass. There isn't any `:fff`. There is `.fff`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(CompletedDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", null);
```

Comment: Using `null` as an `IFormatProvider` is _usually_ a bad idea. Since it replace with `CurrentCulture`, it _might_ use `TimeSeparator` different than `:` character or _might_ have different `Calendar` than Gregorian and this `DateTime` _might_ not exist on that calendar.

Comment: @SonerGönül Sorry. I just focused arrangement of parameters. I dont know whats application culture.